# How can I run a single Android Test using Kotlin?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin

I am using Kotlin 1.0.3 for Android Development in Unit Testing but when I try to run a single test it runs all tests of the class. Does anyone know how to avoid that behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10814) with the IntelliJ Platform that causes the tests for the entire class to be executed if you try to run a single test method and have an existing run configuration for the entire class.

To run a single method, you need to delete the configuration for the entire class using the Run | Edit Configurations... action.